# Can I use an equation with the vw variable inside nth:child selector in css?

Tags: css, responsive

I want to target child elements incrementally as the viewport width changes. Can i do this with only css?

I was using multiple media queries and the nth-child selector, like this

`div:nth-child(1n + x) {display:none}`

and since x+1 was the number of items i wanted to keep, i tried to replace x with an equation for a line based on the number of items and the viewport width like this

`div:nth-child(1n + ((.0068*100vw)+.78)){display:none}`

with no success. Should this work?

Comment: some setup code would be nice so that we don't all have to do it ourselves. ([mre])

Comment: you cannot achieve this